# Serilog in UWP is not writing the log in D drive

Tags: file, logging, uwp, serilog

I am using Serilog in my UWP application. I can write the log in App LocalState folder without any issue.

But now I want to write the logs in **D:** drive specific folder. I have added the **broadFileSystemAccess** restricted capability and enabled the full access from the settings.

But still it is not creating the file in the specified location and not raising any error.

Anyone know the fix for this? Thanks in advance.

```
var file = @"D:\Logs\Serilog.txt";

Serilog.Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration().WriteTo.File(file).CreateLogger();
```

Comment: It wouldn't raise a normal error. Exceptions thrown by a logger would be written the self log, which is described in [the documentation](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Debugging-and-Diagnostics#selflog).

Answer (score 1):

There is a very important information about **broadFileSystemAccess** capability on the [File access permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions#accessing-additional-locations) document. I'm not sure if you note it.

> This `broadFileSystemAccess` capability only works for APIs in the [Windows.Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/uwp/api/Windows.Storage) namespace.

This point is very important. So, your issue actually is you need to check the `LoggerConfiguration().WriteTo.File(file).CreateLogger()` relevant method if it write to files by using the Windows.Storage APIs.

By my checking, it uses the [StreamWriter](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-file/blob/dev/src/Serilog.Sinks.File/Sinks/File/FileSink.cs#L90) method to write to files. But this method is not included in the [Windows.Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Storage) APIs. So, the issue was very obvious. You need to submit this issue to [Github](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-file/issues) and let the officials to modify this method and make it work in UWP.

Or, if you're interested in [serilog-sinks-file](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-file) source code, you could download it and make the change by yourself, Then, you could compile a custom serilog library version for your UWP project.

Comment: Thank you Xavier! I will check that.